# How to make comparator for qsort so that it could compare private members?

Tags: c++, oop, qsort

I have a protected array in the base class

```
#pragma once
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class Base {
protected:
    int N;
    int array[100];
    friend int compare(const void*, const void*);
};
#endif
```

And I need to sort it in the derived class

```
#include "Derived2.h"

int compare(const void* arg1, const void* arg2)
{
    return (*(int*)arg1 - *(int*)arg2);
}
void Derived2::array_sort() {
    qsort (array, N, sizeof(int), compare);
}
```

Derived.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef DERIVED2_H
#define DERIVED2_H
#include "Base.h"

class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
    void array_sort();
    void array_output();
    friend int compare(const void*, const void*);
};
#endif
```

However I got a access violation error.
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFz23.png)
(I think, my function "compare" is not allowed to read protected fields of the base class)

I even tryed to make function "compare" friend for base class and derived one, it still doesn't work and I get the same error.
If I try to make function compare a derived class method, the project doesn`t compile at all.
How to fix it?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch I cannot use <vector>, it must be an array

Comment: @Cognosce _"it still doesn`t work."_ is a very vague problem description, taken into account that you were told you should post a clear and concise one, or weren't you when posting? You may read how to create a [mcve], and [edit] your question accordingly please!

Comment: @Cognosce — `std::sort` works just fine on a C-style array.

Comment: Once your C++ code compiles with no warnings (using `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) read also the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and of the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger -that takes several hours- and use `gdb` to understand the behavior of your executable; and [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) to hunt memory leaks. Be aware of the [C++ rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html)

Answer (score 2):

Access violation has nothing to do with C++ class member access modes. It indicates that your code reads or writes at memory locations that are not allocated (i.e. out-of-bounds access). It is not clear what causes that, but my guess is that `Base::N` value is greater than 100, which is the size of `Base::array`. Check if you're initializing it correctly (the code you posted doesn't).

Also, as others have recommended already, there is no reason to use `qsort` in C++ since [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) would be more efficient and safe.

Comment: BTW, the [Address Sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) is a useful feature of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) compilers.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it!